# Poisson Regression vs. Exponential_Weibull vs. Cox Regression vs. Negative Binomial

Tags: survival, cox-model, poisson-regression

Problem: I would like to predict the number of days a student continues with school  using student and school level covariates (no censor data). Data includes the number of days that the student stayed in school as well as student demographics. Among poisson, weibull-expontial, negative binomial,and a Cox regression, what would be most appropriate for this problem?

Comment: If you have both student and school level data, then you will violate the assumption of independence and need to account for that. So, the answer is really "none of the above" but the question is also very broad.